# Replacing each regex match with different number

Tags: c++, regex

I have a little problem doing my homework.
I need to make a fraction equation parser where fractions are presented by a|b.
I took all the fractions out of the string into a vector and now I want to replace them in string with subsequent numbers so I have an easier time putting them on stack for the shunting yard algorithm.
For example: 
Changing this string
`2|1+4|1*5|2-18|5`
to
`1+2*3-4`
If I do that I can just call the fraction I want by the numbers in quations which would be indexes.
It would make it alot easier to change it from infix to postfix.
Problem is that I don't really know hot to replace each of those fractions with a different number.
My regex is: `regex reg("\\d+\|\\d+");`

This matches every fraction in the string and now is the part where I don't know how to continue.
Using `regex_replace()` will replace all of the matches with the same thing.
I'd greatly apretiate some help.

Comment: Check out [regex iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).

Comment: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator), and generate a new string with the replaced numbers:

```
const std::string s = "2|1+4|1*5|2-18|5";

std::regex r("\\d+\\|\\d+");
// std::regex r(R"(\d+\|\d+)");  // as a raw-string literal, which reduces the need for backslashes

auto begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
auto end = std::sregex_iterator();

int count = 1;
std::string result;
for (std::sregex_iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i) 
    result += i->prefix().str() + std::to_string(count++);

std::cout << result << '\n'; // prints 1+2*3-4
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/86p8oU).

Comment: As a note, raw strings help, especially in regex: `R"(\d+\|\d+)"`.